# Lazy loading doesn't work when using react-router-dom

Tags: reactjs, webpack, lazy-loading, react-router-dom

**Tried every possible solution available on the web. Please Help.**

1. Ran `npm run eject`
2. Edited package.json file and tried the recommended solution of adding the below code as per https://reactrouter.com/web/guides/code-splitting.

```
  "babel": {
    "presets": [
      "@babel/preset-react"
    ],
    "plugins": [
      "@babel/plugin-syntax-dynamic-import"
    ]
  }
```

Below is my code where I use lazy loading. Only the root route ("/") gets loaded. Nothing is loaded when I visit **localhost:3000/auth**

[image]

```
import React, { useEffect, Suspense } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { Redirect, Route, Switch, withRouter } from 'react-router-dom';

import Layout from './components/Layout/Layout';
import Logout from './containers/Auth/Logout/Logout';
import BurgerBuilder from './containers/BurgerBuilder/BurgerBuilder';
import * as actions from './store/actions/index';

const Checkout = React.lazy(() => import('./containers/Checkout/Checkout'));
const Orders = React.lazy(() => import('./containers/Orders/Orders'));
const Auth = React.lazy(() => import('./containers/Auth/Auth'));

const App = (props) => {
  useEffect(() => {
    props.onTryAutoSignup();
  }, []);

  let routes = (
    <Switch>
      <Route
        path="/auth"
        render={(props) => {
          <Auth {...props} />;
        }}
      />
      <Route path="/" exact component={BurgerBuilder} />
      <Redirect to="/" />
    </Switch>
  );
  if (props.isAuthenticated) {
    routes = (
      <Switch>
        <Route path="/checkout" render={(props) => <Checkout {...props} />} />
        <Route path="/orders" render={(props) => <Orders {...props} />} />
        <Route path="/logout" component={Logout} />
        <Route path="/auth" render={(props) => <Auth {...props} />} />
        <Route path="/" exact component={BurgerBuilder} />
        <Redirect to="/" />
      </Switch>
    );
  }
  return (
    <div>
      <Layout>
        <Suspense fallback={<p>Loading...</p>}>{routes}</Suspense>
      </Layout>
    </div>
  );
};

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return {
    isAuthenticated: state.auth.token !== null,
  };
};

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
  return {
    onTryAutoSignup: () => dispatch(actions.authCheckState()),
  };
};

export default withRouter(connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(App));
```

**My package.json file [package.json](https://pastebin.com/iHMKAGwp)** 
**My webpack config file [webpack.config.js](https://pastebin.com/3VTK4M0E)**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have got my mistake.
The webpack or babel config have nothing to do with lazy loading unless you are using Typescript which I'm not.
I had a syntax error in my code which my IDE failed to recognise.

**Instead of this**

```
<Route
        path="/auth"
        render={(props) => {
          <Auth {...props} />;
        }}
 />
```

**It should have been this**

```
<Route path="/auth" render=(props) => <Auth {...props} /> />
```